# Phone Number Masking in Zk

Tags: zk

I need to add masking for telephone number.Is there any attribute for asking in textbox like primefaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inputMask.jsf 
or we have to add jquery for it.
Below is my code:

```
  <textbox value="@bind(vm.phoneNo)" width="180px" constraint="no empty"/>
```

Below Image showing error message stick to Textbox (Tele)

[image]

Below Image showing error message not stick to Textbox(Tele).This is main issue
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [zk demo](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/effects/form_effect), shows you how to use jq.
But zk got different types of [input elements](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Reference/Input) as well that you may like to use,
cos they got `constraint` attribute where you can define reg ex.
See [`textbox`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Reference/Input/Textbox#Constraint) for example.
If you use MVVM you could use the [`@validator`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Syntax/Data%20Binding/@validator) too. [Here](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/input/form_sample) is a demo of it.

Comment: Thanks it is working for me but I am getting one more issue.When I am entering wrong input, it is showing required message but that popup message is moving on scroll.How to fix that message to that textbox not to move on scroll

Comment: Could you please provide your code? I also added a way for MVVM and in the demo the message is sticky to the textbox.

Comment: Nabil A: But I am using same code as showing in given demo. what is the issue in my code.Only I have not used @validator.In the given demo, there is no role for valdiator in case of Phone.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error please check your layout or provide all code related to view so that I can reproduce.

Comment: I am sorry but I can not help you further, because you use ZK PE/EE which I do not own.

Comment: The best way to say "Thank you" on so is to accept and upvote ;)